# Sum numbers on thefly in a textarea

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea with a value 0.
I am using the code bellow to sum +1 but it becomes 01 or 011 or 0111 etc.

Any ideas?

My code is:

```
<input name="su" type="text" id="su" value="0">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio").change(function() {

    var val1 = this.value;    

    if(val1 == 'true'){
        var addone = "1"; 
        $('#su').val($('#su').val()+addone);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `addone`is a string and jquery's `.val()` returns a string, you are concatenating two strings together, not adding numbers. To add numbers instead, you need to convert both to numbers, like so:

```
 var addone= 1;
 $('#su').val(parseInt($('#su').val())+addone);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because using `+` on an item than involves a string does concatenation instead, for example:

```
0 + "1" -> "01"
```

You need `addone` to be a number and convert `$('#su').val()` to a number as well:

```
var addone = 1; 
$('#su').val( +$('#su').val() + addone );
```

Answer (score 1):

force the input value to be an integer by using [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) by changing

```
$('#su').val($('#su').val()+addone);
```

to

```
$('#su').val(parseInt($('#su').val()) + parseInt(addone));
```

Comment: Close, but `addone` is a string. It's still going to end up being `"01"`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek so just forced addone to be an integer, too ;) ty

Answer (score 0):

`input`'s values are always `string`, if you want to get the numerical values, use `parseInt`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio").change(function() {

    var val1 =parseInt(this.value);    //parseInt this

    if(val1 == 'true'){
        var addone = "1"; 
        $('#su').val(parseInt($('#su').val())+addone); //note this one too;
    }
  });
});
</script>
```